# Getting the approximated time of a web page to load in Java

Tags: java

In a programme I am writing in Java, I generate random (existing) addresses. For each address, I want to calculate something.
I don't want to do this calculation if the page is very big, because then it would take much time.

So I thought, that if I know approximately how much time it would take to get the information, I could determine whether to operate that calculation, or not.

Preciseness is not important; I wouldn't care if it takes a second more than requested (although I wouldn't want it to exceed around 5-6 seconds).

I am generating articles from Wikipedia, if it helps.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean what I think you mean, you could do an HTTP HEAD request for the resource. The webserver would then reply with the headers, but not the content. If it sends the Content-Length header then you know how big the page is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Two questions: (1) How do I do that (I looked it up and couldn't find)? (2) Does it run in a reasonable time?

Comment: (1) You should be able to do it with any decent HTTP library, I like Apache's HttpClient. (2) Not necessarily, at the end of the day there's no way to predict how long a webserver will take to respond, but in general the HEAD response should be fast, and shouldn't take longer if the page is bigger or anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing it (if it's supported by server). For example using URLconnection, Apache HttpClient ...

- for 1st you can use `Connection.getContentLength();`
- for 2nd request header of page:  `client.execute(requestHead);` then read Content-Length element from response

bad thing for any method is that sometimes server doesn't give any information about size so you can end up with value of **-1**